# How to ignore warning for program that connects to VPN

Tags: macos, security, vpn

I have to click accept/allow on this dialog everytime I launch a process that goes out to the web via the VPN..is there some env var I can set which can ignore the warning?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

The dialog box tells you how to solve the problem.

[image: Security Dialog]

> This setting can be changed in the firewall pane of the Security & Privacy Settings

There are excellent guides provided by Apple that can walk you through the process

- [Change Firewall preferences on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-euro/guide/mac-help/mh11783/mac)
- [Use a firewall to prevent unwanted connections on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-euro/guide/mac-help/mh11783/mac)

But basically, what you're going to do is add your application, `cm_api` to your firewall and allow it incoming and outgoing connections.  Remember, you must be an admin to make this change.